# front end customer session expire issue

Tags: customer, session

logged out immediately After login customer in front end .

i checked in system->configuration->session Cookie management and cookie life time is 36000000.
for only one website->store view only its not working properly.for other store views there is no problem with customer session management.

note:same instance in local also there is no problem at all.

can you any one give idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are there different URLs/URL paths involved?